# Are the DFT/FFT multiplications in the fourier domain complex multiplications?

Tags: fft

If you want to compute a convolution with a DFT/FFT, you will have to do a DFT on the image and a DFT on the kernel.

And you will need to multiply the spectrum of the image with the spectrum of the kernel.

Is it correct that the  multiplications in the fourier domain are complex multiplications? So, that those point-wise multiplications will require 4 real multiplications and 2 real additions?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Yes, you will be multiplying 2 complex numbers at a time.

Comment: @pichenettes and Mohammad: hey guys, please make an answer out of it, even though you may think it's trivial; otherwise this question will be one more on the pile of unanswered questions ...

Comment: Yes :) ex. (a+jb)*(c+jd) = (ac-bd) + j (cb + ad) ==> 4 Real Multiplications, and 2 Real Additions

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct - the DFT/FFT of a real signal (for example an image) is not necessarily real; so if you want to compute a convolution through multiplications in the Fourier domain, the coefficients to multiply will be complex numbers; and will thus cost 4 real multiplications and 2 real additions if a naive implementation is used (unless the architecture you are writing code for has hardware support for complex multiplications).